# Qual é a diferença entre [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] e [HttpGet]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Pra que serve `HttpGet` e pra que serve `AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)` ?

Exemplo:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId)
{
    return ....
}
```

Outro Exemplo:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId)
{
    return ....
}
```

Qual é a funcionalidades entre elas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe diferença nesse dois trechos de código, eles tem o mesmo proposito,  para que o método só aceita requisições do [`verb`](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) `GET`, na verdade um é *abreviação* do outro. No código ***fonte*** do [HttpGetAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HttpGetAttribute.cs) fica bem claro que é a abreviação para [AcceptVerbsAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AcceptVerbsAttribute.cs):

*Código* [***HttpGetAttribute***](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HttpGetAttribute.cs):

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class HttpGetAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        private static readonly AcceptVerbsAttribute _innerAttribute = 
                                        new AcceptVerbsAttribute(HttpVerbs.Get);

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                               MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return _innerAttribute
                       .IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>**Fonte e direitos autoriais** *Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved* no [link](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HttpGetAttribute.cs)</sub>

---

Uma vantagem de usar atributo [`AcceptVerbs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.acceptverbsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) é que pode conter mais de um tipo de [`verb`](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) configurado, ***exemplo***:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

*ou*

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
```

sendo assim o método aceita requisições dos [`verb`](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) `GET` ou `POST` no exemplo.

<sup>***Observações:*** Vale lembrar que se não houver nenhum configuração (`[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]` ou `[AcceptVerbs("POST")]`, etc.) o método aceita por padrão o [`verb`](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) `GET`</sup>

***Referencias:***

- [AcceptVerbsAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.acceptverbsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [HttpGet Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.activities.messaging.httpget(v=azure.10).aspx)
- [*Fonte* HttpGetAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HttpGetAttribute.cs)
- [*Fonte* AcceptVerbsAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AcceptVerbsAttribute.cs)
- [Como escolher entre solicitações HTTP POST e HTTP GET para pontos de extremidade AJAX ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb628610(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)
- [What is the difference between [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] and [HttpPost]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843875/what-is-the-difference-between-acceptverbshttpverbs-post-and-httppost)
- [Using HTTP Methods for RESTful Services](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)
- [9 Method Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)